# Angular interceptor does not intercept errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have interceptor, however it all responses only goes into `request()`, even if 500 code returned

Here is my code

```
angular.module("BusinessTool").factory('InterceptorService',['$q', '$location', function( $q, $location, $http ){
    resp = $.get('api/me.json');
    return {
        request: function(config){
            // everything is ok
            return config;
        },

        responseError: function(rejection) {
            //error here. for example server respond with 401
            if (resp.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = '/';
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);



angular.module("BusinessTool").config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorService');
}]);
```

I want to redirect to `/` url in case of 401. Also is it possible to force interceptor to do request to `api/me.json` before each request?

Comment: I think you are confusing `request` with `response` the request method will be called *before* the $http request. Check this: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: This also may answer your second question, since request method will be called before every request, you can do this json retrieve inside of it.

Comment: @ItaloAyres Thanks, missed this point. Put your comments into answer, so i could accept it